# Submit html input without a trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I have this following line that needs a fix:

```
 <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="searchdesc" value="{$smarty.get.user}" class="search-field" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="loadXMLDoc('search/?tip={$smarty.get.tip}&user='+encode(this.value)+'&page={$smarty.get.page}','searchResult');" />
```

The important part is the onkeyup function. I need to change it to a function that automatically triggers without any contact with the input, because I won't need to press,focus,click the input(it will have a value set with the value property). Is there a function that can just load that XML without having contact with the input?

Comment: Use `onkeyup="function() { myFuncCallHere(); }"`

Comment: why? It will never trigger since I will never key up anything inside the input

Comment: then simply call your `loadXMLDoc()` in a `<script>` tag just below this `<input>` box

Comment: welcome @Victor...`:)`!